# Unable to encode MKPolyline or MKPolygon using NSCoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoding

I am trying to save my an MKPolyline and MKPolygon view in NSUserDefaults. I have a model where I've implemented:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
```

However whenever I attempt to encode my MKPolyLine I get an error:

```
-[MKPolyline encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I set an all exceptions breakpoint and it stops at this line:

```
[aCoder encodeObject:self.layerData forKey:@"layer"];
```

The property for layerData is:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKPolyline *layerData;
```

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: You put your class NSCoding compliant in order to `initWithCoder:/encodeWithCoder:` to save it into `NSUserDefaults` (i.e. transform it into NSData). Well, MKPolyline doesn't comply with NSCoding. What you could do instead, is to save the points or coordinates and (theses should be easily saved) and recreated the MKPolyline from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can implement NSCoding for MKPolyline, and you can make a NSData representation and store that in NSUserDefaults, which can be stored in key value form in NSUserDefaults.

Construct an array if you have a single line or multiple arrays and bind them with respective key/values making them form a dictionary. Which has the x and y values for each point, and store that in NSUserDefaults.

When loading defaults, get the array, loop through the single array in case of single line and dictionary if you have multiple MKPolyline. Then re-create the MKPolyline with the points.

Comment: Yeah, I just converted my array of annotation CLLocationCoordinate2D to CLLocation. I just have to iterate back over my array of stored CLLocation items and convert. Seems to be working just fine. I gave you credit because your answer helped lead me to the solution. Thanks!